# MVC Html.HIddenFor value not being passed to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am working with JQueryUI Datepicker, and this is the code I am using in the view

```
@model myprojectName.WebSite.DataModel.AvailableDate

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});


</script>
<h3 class="headerColorWhite">Book a session with Mike</h3>
<p class="mainText">Select a date that you wish to train with Mike</p>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="editor-field left" id="datepicker">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateAvailable, new {@class = "datepicker"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateAvailable)
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 left">
    <input type="submit" value="Search Available Slots" class="btn btn-default left" />
</div>
}
```

When hitting the submit \ search available slots button, this doesn't appear to be sending my selected date back to the model.

This is the Model that its passing the date to

```
public partial class AvailableDate
{
    private DateTime? _DateAvailable;

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public System.DateTime DateAvailable
    {
        get { return _DateAvailable ?? DateTime.Today; }
        set { _DateAvailable = value; }
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong and what I need to do in order to fix this.

--------------- edit to show get and post methods---------------

```
// GET: Bookings
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(AvailableDate availableDate)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What does the signature of your controller method look like...

Comment: Please provide the GET and POST actions from your controller.

Comment: I am using a hiddenFor field because I want the datepicker to be permanently visible and not show only when the a textbox is hit. Also when using the textbox, it doesnt format right, but thats a question for another time

Comment: code edited to show the get and post of this page so far, when i get the right dates coming back then I will be adding a new partialView to get a list of available dates

Comment: I'm sorry - it took me a few seconds after I posted that comment to realise why you were using a hidden field, hence the edit. Thanks for the update.

Comment: when you convert the div to a datepicker you're not setting the name attribute to `DateAvailable`..  maybe you can set the name like this `<div class="editor-field left" id="datepicker" name="DateAvailable">`

Comment: I just tried that and there was not change in the results i am seeing, its still sends back today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the hidden field `DateAvailable` will always be set to null. When you click a date from the data picker, it isn't currently updating the hidden field.

So, instead of

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

try:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText, e) {
            $("#DateAvailable").val($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

This will assign the hidden field a value. Also, as discussed in our conversion, the date would need to be formatted, as defined by `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'` above.

Comment: still getting the same result

Comment: When you click on a date, what is the value of `DateAvailable`?

Comment: how would i check this?

Comment: On Google Chrome, open up Developer Tools by hitting F12. Then you can either CTRL + F for "DateAvailable" or type `$("#DateAvailable").val();` in the console.

Comment: thats gives me the selected date

Comment: Okay, good. Can you paste the exact format? Also, when you debug your application, is the `DateAvailable` variable null on the POST request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88738/discussion-between-rhys-and-simon-price).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the selected date is applied to the hidden field? Maybe you should use [`altField`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  altField: ".datepicker"
});
```

where `.datepicker` would be the class you inject for the hidden field. Or better use its id and apply a format:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  altField: "#DateAvailable",
  altFormat: "dd-mm-yy" // added for conversion compatibility
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/re59d4j4/).

Comment: using this code snippet the datepicker doesnt event show on the page

Comment: I use firebug for client side debugging. If the value of the hidden field changes, you can see it there. Without `altField` nothing happens.

Comment: i wasnt using the code right, but the snippet you gave still doesnt pass the value back but am about to checkout firebug

Comment: Well, in that case the last thing I could think of is a wrong format which cannot be converted. Maybe check that. I updated my answer.

Comment: got it working with Rhys's solution, but thank you very much for your time and help too